# My PHP upload script is not uploading all the multiple files, it seems to upload random ones. No errors appear, I can't find the fault

Tags: php, file, post, upload, php-8.2

I have a HTML form which I send to a php page, the form seems to upload some files but not others.
For example if I upload six files, what seems to happen is 2 or 3 will upload and the others won't. I also send the filename to a database, which shows the same 2 or 3 files repeated.

I have checked all the timeout options, post sizes and cannot fathom the cause. I haven't placed any restrictions on the file types (yet).

The HTML code:

```html
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="frm-activity-files"><h3>Attach files:</h3></label>
    <input type="file" multiple="multiple" name="frm-activity-files[]">
    <p>Files limited to 10MB each.</p>
</form>
```

The PHP Code:

```php
<?php
$frm_upload_count = 0;
$frm_upload_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/uploads/';

if (!empty($_FILES['frm-activity-files']['tmp_name'])) {
    $error = '';
    $frm_upload_count = count($_FILES['frm-activity-files']['tmp_name']);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $frm_upload_count; $i++) {

        $frm_upload_newname = (md5(date('Y-m-d H:i:s:u')).'-'.date('YmdHis'));
        $frm_upload_file = $_FILES['frm-activity-files']['name'][$i];
        $frm_upload_temp = $_FILES['frm-activity-files']['tmp_name'][$i];

        $frm_upload_ext = pathinfo($frm_upload_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $frm_upload_rename = $frm_upload_newname.'.'.$frm_upload_ext;

        move_uploaded_file($frm_upload_temp, $frm_upload_path.$frm_upload_rename);

        $sql_insert_attachment = 'INSERT INTO data__attachments(attachment_auuid, attachment_uid, attachment_filename) VALUES (?,?,?)';
        $stmt_insert_attachment = $mysqli->prepare($sql_insert_attachment);
        $stmt_insert_attachment->bind_param("sss", $frm_uuid, $frm_uid, $frm_upload_rename);
        $stmt_insert_attachment->execute();

        $frm_upload_newname = "";
        $frm_upload_file = "";
        $frm_upload_temp = "";

        $frm_upload_ext = "";
        $frm_upload_rename = "";

        $error .= $_FILES['frm-activity-files']['error'][$i]; // get the error
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you see if you do `var_dump($_FILES)`? Does it have all 6 files in it?

Comment: check the values of upload_max_filesize, post_max_size, and max_file_uploads in php.ini

Comment: And if you check the Network tab in Developer Tools, can you see all 6 files being uploaded in the payload?

Comment: Do you have proper PHP error reporting enabled, and your database connection set to throw exceptions when any errors occur? If you put any debug output _after_ the `for` loop, do you actually receive that on the client side then?

Comment: @Barmar, the `var_dump($_FILES)` output shows all six files as arrays.

Comment: Out of all six that appeared in the array, only one uploaded successfully on this occasion.

Comment: @PanktiShah, I increased the `max_execution_time` to 300, `max_file_uploads` to 100, `post_max_size` to 500M, `upload_max_filesize` to 500M,

Comment: @CBroe, apart from `$_FILES['frm-activity-files']['error']` set up to catch the errors, the top of the page also has `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: _"the var_dump($_FILES) output shows all six files as arrays"_ - and what does the `error` property for each one say in there?

Comment: @Barmar on checking the network tab in developer tools it shows request method POST, status code 200, under the response it shows all the arrays again without issue.

Comment: @CBroe The error property for each just displays 0

Comment: You have done no success/error checking on the `move_uploaded_file` call, and without seeing your connection settings, we can't know whether a faulty database query would actually throw an exception, or would simply pass unnoticed.

Comment: @CBroe   , I changed the code to ` $move_file = move_uploaded_file($frm_upload_temp, $frm_upload_path . $frm_upload_rename); if($move_file){ $frm_check .= 'Successful Upload of file ' . $i; } else { $frm_check .= 'Error ' . $_FILES['frm-activity-files']['error'][$i] . 'happened'; }`. Each time the result shows successful. The database records the successful uploads, but for the ones that are unsuccessful it still inputs it with the previous filename

Comment: _"The database records the successful uploads, but for the ones that are unsuccessful it still inputs it with the previous filename"_ - you are not updating any records there, you are inserting new ones. So where on earth could this _possibly_ get any "previous" file name from, at this point? The `$frm_upload_rename` value was created by you in that script, as the hash of a value based on the current date & time.

Comment: @CBroe Not the response, the payload.

Comment: @CBroe - I uploaded it to a test server on the internet rather than my own local docker and it only uploads one of each extension, for example if I upload a .jpg, .png, .pdf, .zip it will accept all four files, if I try and upload 4 .jpg files it will only upload the first but the database will record the remaining three with the previous filename.

Comment: _"but the database will record the remaining three with the previous filename"_ - if the file name you are generating is the exact same each time, then `move_uploaded_file` will overwrite them.

Comment: It turns out the files uploaded too quickly and the newname was not generating a new name based on the date time. I altered the code from `$frm_upload_newname = (md5(date('Y-m-d H:i:s:u')).'-'.date('YmdHis'));` to ` $frm_upload_newname  = (substr(md5($_FILES['frm-activity-files']['name'][$i]),0,10).'-'.date('YmdHisu'));` and it worked fine.

Comment: Thank you @CBroe for all the help, your last comment made me think to change the newname.